# Couldn't find package libncurses5-dev

Tags: vim, ubuntu-10.04

While installing Vim 7.3 on ubuntu 10.04 LTS, I encounter an error as below

> checking --with-tlib argument...
> empty: automatic terminal library
> selection
>
> checking for tgetent in -lncurses...
> no
>
> checking for tgetent in -ltermlib...
> no
>
> checking for tgetent in -ltermcap...
> no
>
> checking for tgetent in -lcurses... no
> no terminal library found
>
> checking for tgetent()... configure:
> error: NOT FOUND!
>
> ```
>   You need to install a terminal library; for example ncurses.
>
>   Or specify the name of the library with --with-tlib.
> ```

and then I googled and found that I need to install **libncurses-dev**, so I typed

> $ sudo apt-get install libncurses-dev
>
> Package libncurses-dev is not available, but is referred to by
>
> another package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been
>
> obsoleted, or is only available from another source
>
> E: Package libncurses-dev has no installation candidate

When I change **libncurses-dev** to **libncurses5-dev**, I got error

> $ sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev
>
> E: Couldn't find package
> libncurses5-dev

So what happened?

Thank you.

Comment: http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/libncurses5-dev - repos set up properly? Maybe do a `apt-get update`?

Answer (score 4):

Certainly solved and not really related to your initial problem but might help someone :)

Check that you have libncurses5-dev package installed

```
sudo aptitude search %p libncurses
```

---

This should give you something like:

> i libncurses5 - Bibliothèques partagées pour l'utilisation d'un terminal
>   i libncurses5-dev - developer's libraries for ncurses

which here means that the package is installed

Same result with:

```
find /usr -name "libncurse*"
```

---

If not:

```
sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev
```

Then to configure vim with maximum options:

```
./configure --with-features=huge --with-tlib=ncurses
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to Sytem -> Administration -> Software Sources and make sure that you have all the relevant sources checked. Then do a `apt-get update`

This might help:

http://www.liberiangeek.net/2010/06/configuring-software-sources-ubuntu-10-04-lucid-lynx-receive-updatespatches/

Answer (score 0):

Fix Error configure: error: libncurses5-dev is missing on centos

[root@centos601 ~]# yum install ncurses-devel

http://centostoday.com/configure-error-libncurses5-dev-missing.html

Comment: OP was asking about Ubuntu, not Centos